# more ruby way of doing project euler #2

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby, and am going through some of the Project Euler problems. I solved [problem number two](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2) as such:

```
def fib(n)
  return n if n < 2
  vals = [0, 1]
  n.times do
    vals.push(vals[-1]+vals[-2])
  end
  return vals.last
end
i = 1
s = 0
while((v = fib(i)) < 4_000_000)
  s+=v if v%2==0
  i+=1
end
puts s
```

While that works, it seems not very ruby-ish—I couldn't come up with any good purely Ruby answer like I could with the first one ( `puts (0..999).inject{ |sum, n| n%3==0||n%5==0 ? sum : sum+n }`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a nice solution, why don't you create a Fibonacci number generator, like `Prime` or the  `Triangular` example I [gave here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024452/more-ruby-like-solution-to-this-problem/3026213#3026213).

From this, you can use the nice `Enumerable` methods to handle the problem. You might want to wonder if there is any pattern to the even Fibonacci numbers too.

Edit your question to post your solution...

Note: there are more efficient ways than enumerating them, but they require more math, won't be as clear as this and would only shine if the 4 million was much higher.

As demas' has posted a solution, here's a cleaned up version:

```
class Fibo
  class << self
    include Enumerable

    def each
      return to_enum unless block_given?
      a = 0; b = 1
      loop do
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Fibo.take_while { |i| i < 4000000 }.
          select(&:even?).
          inject(:+)
```

Comment: If you get stuck writing such a generator, have a look at the following: http://www.davidflanagan.com/2007/08/fibonacci-numbers-with-ruby-19-fibers.html

Comment: @Michael: oh my! That post is a _terrible_ use of `Fiber` and way too complex (let alone slow). If you need something like it, write a good enumerable (have a look at the triangular number generator I pointed to) and get an `Enumerator` and use `next`, but even that should be avoided.

Comment: I post my version below. Pls, check it. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune why do you pass `i` to the block in `1.upto(Float::INFINITY) do |i|`? It doesn't look like you are using it... also, can you explain how the Float::INFINITY works here? To me it reads "do something forever" but obviously I am wrong.

Comment: @Mohamad This was from dema's answer below, but you are right this can be simplified further. I've edited my answer accordingly. No you are right, it is an infinity loop, but using it as an enumerable makes it easy to take only a few of the items.

Answer (score 2):

My version based on Marc-André Lafortune's answer:

```
class Some
  @a = 1
  @b = 2

  class << self
    include Enumerable

    def each
      1.upto(Float::INFINITY) do |i|
        @a, @b = @b, @a + @b
        yield @b
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Some.take_while { |i| i < 4000000 }.select { |n| n%2 ==0 }
          .inject(0) { |sum, item| sum + item } + 2
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to go about it. I edited my answer with a slightly improved version.

Comment: Note that one problem with your version is you can't call it more than once... `Some.first # => 3; Some.first => 5`

Answer (score 2):

```
def fib
  first, second, sum = 1,2,0
  while second < 4000000
    sum += second if second.even?
    first, second = second, first + second
  end
  puts sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `return vals.last`. You can just do `vals.last`, because Ruby will return the last expression (I think that's the correct term) by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
fibs = [0,1]
begin
  fibs.push(fibs[-1]+fibs[-2])
end while not fibs[-1]+fibs[-2]>4000000
puts fibs.inject{ |sum, n| n%2==0 ? sum+n : sum }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got. I really don't see a need to wrap this in a class. You could in a larger program surely, but in a single small script I find that to just create additional instructions for the interpreter. You could select even, instead of rejecting odd but its pretty much the same thing.

```
fib = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a = b = 1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end

puts fib.take_while{|i| i < 4000000}
        .reject{|x| x.odd?}
        .inject(:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my approach. I know it can be less lines of code, but maybe you can take something from it.

```
class Fib
  def first
    @p0 = 0
    @p1 = 1
    1
  end
  def next
    r = 
      if @p1 == 1
        2
      else
        @p0 + @p1
      end
    @p0 = @p1
    @p1 = r
    r
  end
end

c = Fib.new
f = c.first
r = 0
while (f=c.next) < 4_000_000
  r += f if f%2==0
end
puts r
```

Comment: If you start with `@p0 = 1`, you can get rid of your `if`... Also, Ruby has parallel assignment which can be useful here. Did you know that `2.even?` returns `true`?

Comment: I know that. I just posted my archive code from my Project Euler tasks archive. I wrote this a long ago.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Ruby, but here is the answer I came up with.

```
 x=1
 y=2
 array = [1,2]
 dar = [] 
   begin
     z = x + y

       if z % 2 == 0
         a = z
         dar << a
       end
     x = y
     y = z
     array << z
   end while z < 4000000
     dar.inject {:+}
     puts "#{dar.sum}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fib_nums(num)
    array = [1, 2]
    sum = 0
    until array[-2] > num
        array.push(array[-1] + array[-2])
    end
    array.each{|x| sum += x if x.even?}
    sum
end
```